# How to register new Twig Namespaces from inside a Bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I search for a way to change the configuration of the Symfony twig bundle in order to register additional twig namespaces.

I tripped over [prepend extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html) but this would just solve the problem half way. When I write code like this:

```
public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $bundles = $container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');

        if (isset($bundles['TwigBundle'])) {

            $config = $container->getExtensionConfig('twig')[0];
            $paths = ['/path/to/cms' => 'cms'];

            if (array_key_exists('path', $config)) {
                $paths = array_merge($config['paths'], $paths);
            }

            $config['paths'] = $paths;

            $container->prependExtensionConfig('twig', $config);
        }
    }
```

This would mean that no other bundle could ever change the twig configuration again:

> [image: more then one bundle]

How to add twig namespaces from inside a bundle without obstructing a way for other bundles to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a Compiler Pass within your Bundle:

```
class CustomCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        if ($container->hasDefinition('twig.loader.native_filesystem')){
            $bundleDirectory = \dirname(__DIR__,2);
            $twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition = $container->getDefinition('twig.loader.native_filesystem');
            $twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition->addMethodCall('addPath', [$bundleDirectory.'/templates/admin', 'admin']);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Twig namespaces are an **application** concern, not a bundle concern.

Registering new namespaces from within the bundle could clash with already defined namespaces by the application that consumes the bundle.

Furthermore, it's not necessary, because Symfony [already auto-crates a namespace for each bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#bundle-templates):

> If you install packages/bundles in your application, they may include their own Twig templates (in the `Resources/views/` directory of each bundle). To avoid messing with your own templates, Symfony adds bundle templates under an automatic namespace created after the bundle name.
>
> For example, the templates of a bundle called `AcmeFooBundle` are available under the `AcmeFoo` namespace. If this bundle includes the template `<your-project>/vendor/acmefoo-bundle/Resources/views/user/profile.html.twig`, you can refer to it as `@AcmeFoo/user/profile.html.twig`.

You shouldn't mess with that configuration. Leave it up to the application developer or the framework to deal with it.